# jQuery keypress event for many dynamically added textareas

Tags: events, jquery, dynamically-generated

I want to write a little chat. 
On the first load of the page old messages and answers will be loaded from the database. So I have many messages with different IDs. For every message I have a link to reply. When you click on it a message box appears. My problem is, that I want to send the reply when the user press Enter on his keyboard.

The reply textareas are added with jquery so I can't use $(textarea).keypress(.....)

Here is a example of my code:

```
 <div id="container" style="">
<div id="main" role="main">
    <div id="shoutbox_container">
        <div id="shoutbox_content" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
for (id = 0; id < 5; id++) {
   var res_container = '<div id="shoutbox_entry_' + id + '" class="entry entrybox">';
   res_container += 'Mr Idontknow wrote:' + id + '. Message ';
   res_container += ' <span class="reply" id="reply" data-parentid="' + id + '">reply</span> ';
   res_container += '<div class="replytextbox replybox" id="reply_textbox_' + id + '" style="display:none;">';
   res_container += '<textarea class="replytext" name="antwort" id="antwort_' + id + '" data-parentid="' + id + '"></textarea>';
   res_container += '<button id="replysend">send</button> ';
   res_container += '</div>';
   res_container += '</div><br><br>';
   $('#shoutbox_content').prepend(res_container);   } 

//reply textarea   
$('#shoutbox_content').on('click', '#reply', function () {
   var parentid = $(this).data('parentid');
   $('#shoutbox_content').find('#reply_textbox_' + parentid).toggle();
});

//reply send button
$('#shoutbox_content').on('click', 'button', function () {
   var parentid = $(this).prev('textarea').data('parentid');
   var reply = $(this).prev('textarea').val();
   $(this).prev('textarea').val('');
   $('#shoutbox_content').find('#reply_textbox_' + parentid).hide();

   if (reply.length > 0) {
       alert('save reply ' + parentid);
   }
});

// when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
$('#shoutbox_content').keypress('textarea', function (e) {
   if (e.which == 13) {
       console.log($(this).find('textarea'));
       var test = $(this).attr('data-parentid');
       alert('Enter ' + test);
       $(this).blur();
       $(this).next('#replysend').focus().click();
   }
});
```

It works but I don't know which ID was send. Has anybody an idea how I can find out in which reply textarea the user pressed Enter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, use .on() function like others events declaration you are using :

```
// when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
$('#shoutbox_content').on('keypress','textarea', function (e) {

   //Retrieve ID of the textarea
   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   //Do what you want with id variable

   if (e.which == 13) {
       console.log($(this).find('textarea'));
       var test = $(this).attr('data-parentid');
       alert('Enter ' + test);
       $(this).blur();
       $(this).next('#replysend').focus().click();
   }
});
```

Then retrieve the textarea where the event occurred by checking its ID or another attribute like this : `$(this).attr('id')`